# Getting Value Of Radio Button And Label Text Put Into Two TextField

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to get value form label (radio) and value of radio button. When I click label or radio button, they value input into their respective textfield

```
o 1
• 2
o 3
o 4

 value radio    value label
____________   ______________
|    72    |   |     2      |
|__________|   |____________|
```

I try create on jsfiddle but not working, only value radio button insert into text field.

See **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HfCCT/)**

How do I create function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change doesn't occur on the label. You need to use the change of the radio for both.

```
$('input[name="20"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[class="20"]').val($(this).val());
        $('input[class="1_20"]').val($(this).parent().text());
        });
```

Comment: If you liked my answer, please mark it as an answer to show this question was answered

Comment: @A.V sorry, its actually `id` is different, I copy & paste in order to quickly. Thanks